# Permission denied when trying to execute behat in jenkins

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, behat, jenkins-php

I try to execute behat in my jenkins server (similar to [this](http://shaneauckland.co.uk/2013/01/integrating-behat-and-mink-with-jenkinsci/)).

My build xml:

```
<target name="behat" description="Execute the behat tests">
    <exec command="${basedir}/bin/behat --profile jenkins -c ${basedir}/config/behat.yml"  />       
</target>
```

(Yes, my bin is at ./bin and not ./vendor/bin)

However I get this error:

```
var/lib/jenkins/jobs/defTest/workspace/build.xml:116: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/defTest/workspace/bin/behat": error=13, Keine Berechtigung
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Keine Berechtigung
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 23 more

("Keine Berechtigung" is German for "Permission denied") I tried to chmod the behat file to 777 but as I pull from a mercurial repository my changes seem always to be undone.

Do you have any ideas how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a prebuild shell task:

chmod 777 /PATH_TO_BEHAT/bin/behat

Comment: This works, thanks. An alternativ seems to be to install behat from http://pear.behat.org/ and use these scripts.

Comment: Worked for a different script as well (gradlew).